# Where does Keepass2Android store its password files?

Tags: applications, files

I've been using Keepass2Android for a while. I try to store my files in DropBox so I can access across multiple devices. I have noticed that somehow I have some copies of my `mypasswords.kdbx` file that are listed as being in the `content://`. I've searched around and can't find `mypasswords.kdbx` file anywhere on my phone.

In desktop KeePass, I can synchronize two password files that have the same master password, but this doesn't seem to work in Keepass2Android.

Does anyone know where `content://` is located?

Comment: As far as I know Dropbox synchronized keepass2android files are kept in the app internal memory (only accessible with root permissions). `content://` is a scheme that is defined by keepass2android and seems to allows to specify the file-name when you open the app.

Comment: Do you know where content:// exists?  I can't find it with total commander.  I've tried searching for "mypasswords*"  When I search for *.kdbx it seems to find a bunch of stuff that isn't a keepass file.  I've tried the stock files app  on my Samsung phone and it doesn't work either.  I've also tried connecting my phone as as drive but it doesn't work either.

Comment: `content://` does not exist at all, it is an activity implemented by the app itself that accepts this as a parameter (defined in it's AndroidManifest.xml). If you use a content:// url when starting the app the app gets this just like a command-line parameter on a command-line application.

Answer (score 0):

My file that's just in `content://` is the one in OneDrive. I know this because there's a password in there that's not in the file I actually want to be using, in `gdrive://(username)/(filename).kdbx`. I opened the OneDrive file from OneDrive into KeePass2Android, and there was the password.

Answer (score 0):

`content://` is where Keepass2Android keeps its local password database(s). You can't access it, maybe you can see it if you root your phone. I think it's safest to choose [3-dot menu] > Settings > Database > Export database... and control where it makes a copy.

Keepass2Android has a way to synchronize with an external `.kdbx`. For those who want to manually synchronize (e.g. you're using Keepass2Android Offline), I've created an issue to add the steps to [its documentation](https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android/blob/master/docs/Documentation.md), and [my issue](https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android/issues/1998) has the steps that worked for me.